# God won't give us more than we can handle?

Tags: verse-identification

Does the Bible state that God will not give us more than we can handle? Is it stated anywhere in the Bible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because verse search questions are off-topic.

Comment: I'm regretting closing this, but when you ask an open ended question about what the Bible says or doesn't say it is open to interpretation.  I think you could ask "what is the Biblical basis for some Christians saying that God doesn't give us more than we can handle" but as it stands, we don't support verse ID questions on this website as a policy.

Answer (score 2):

The passage most commonly associated with this idea is [1 Corinthians 10:13 (NLT)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20cor%2010%3A13&version=NLT):

> The temptations in your life are no different from what others experience. And God is faithful. He will not allow the temptation to be more than you can stand. When you are tempted, he will show you a way out so that you can endure.